# Automatic Transmission is Skipping 2nd Gear

Tags: ford, transmission, escape

I have a 2008 Ford Escape XLT. I was recently told that it is revving up high before shifting because 2nd gear is gone, so it is going from 1st gear to 3rd. Will it ruin the other gears if I drive it too long like this? How much longer can I drive it like this? I know I need a new transmission but it will take me a bit before I can get one.

Comment: Is that what a transmission shop told you? You may want to get a second opinion from another shop before you replace the transmission. Are there any codes? How's the fluid level? Does the transmission slip?

Comment: Yes a transmission shop told me that. The fluid level is good. when I start out driving it goes slow and revs up to over 3500 rpm before it kicks into  the next gear, then after that it goes fine. there is a light that comes on in the shape of a wrench and in the manual it say for that symbol it is the throttle control / powertrain the manual also says that the light illuminates when a powertrain fault has been detected to contact the dealer as soon as possible.

Comment: Sounds like the electric throttle body controller. If it pulls a code p2111 or p2112 that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends what really happened to that 2nd gear. If it's just the shift solenoid that went bad, you'll be ok, and it's actually simple to fix. But if the gear is physically damaged, it is shedding or has shed metal fragments.

There are magnets in the tranny pan to catch these, but they are only designed to handle normal wear and tear (and stray nuts, as I've found out), they may get overwhelmed with the amount of metal coming from a shredded gear.

What exactly happened to your 2nd gear?

Comment: The Mechanic did not tell me exactly what happened he just said 2nd gear is gone and that I need a new transmission. He put it on his computer and then took it for a ride around the block. and when he came back that is when he told me it was shot.

Comment: Replacing an entire transmission is way more expensive than just replacing a solenoid. Ask exactly what is wrong with the transmission, and ask for a 2nd opinion at another shop. Solenoids are cheap and easy.